# Grails 2.x Maven Ear project fixtures integration tests break

Tags: maven, grails, ear, fixtures

I have an EAR project setup with Maven using Grails 2.1.1

```
Root
   ear
   war
     grails-app
     fixtures
     ...
```

This is a Grails project and it uses the fixtures plugin for integration testing.

```
If I run
    mvn grails:test-app
From the 'war' folder everything runs fine.


If I run
    mvn package

from the Root folder, then during the testing phase the fixtures plugin is unable to load the fixtures resources as it cannot find them.
```

It would appear the plugin is using a context at the Root level in order to try and resolve the fixtures resources that reside in the 'war' folder. I tend to classify this as a "grails test runner" bug in that it appears to not be setting the application context to the proper folder when it goes to run the test phase.
Has anyone seen this behavior before and any idea how to fix it? I've tried debugging the fixtures plugin and as I say it appears to be using the appropriate grailsApplication and servletContext, I'm just not sure the grailsApplication context is setup properly.

Comment: Same problem came up with the database-migration plugin. It seems to expect that the build is always started at the Grails project root. In multi module projects and most enterprise projects this is not the case. I haven't found a solution yet.